# How to remove the function minimize sidebar in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, editor

How can I remove the little sidebar to the left of the code in Visual Studio 2019? I mean the little minus signs that appear next to each function or code block header and, if clicked, minimize that function or code block.

Is there a way to disable these?

Answer (score 1):

The feature is known as "outlining" and enabling/disabling it is language-specific. In all cases, use the "Options" command from the "Tools" menu and then, in the left-hand pane of the displayed pop-up box, open the "Text Editor" node.

For C/C++ files, the option is under the "View" sub-node:
[image]

For C# files (and also Basic, F# and Python), it's under "Advanced":
[image]

For other languages, it's likely to be in one or other of those places, but I can't guarantee that. In all cases, changes only come into effect on files that are opened *after* the option is changed.

If you have another specific language for which you can't find this option, just let me know and I'll try to help.