# Visual Studio 2019 16.9.4: ThreeState for collapsing and expanding summary

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I encountered today that with one of the latest releases of Visual Studio, it seems that the collaps / expand function now has a third state for the summary block.

When I expand the '#region Methods' (see pictures) all methods are displayed only with three dots [...]

[image: undesired look after expanding region]

Why aren't the method names displayed anymore as it was before?

Is it possible to have it the old way again?
[image: desired look after expanding region]

Is there a setting?
I already tried to find a setting for it in the options, but couldn't find any when searching for the following words:

1. collaps
2. expand
3. summary
4. threestate

Comment: The expand/collapse feature in VS is called "outlining" ([possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67051532/10871073)). I can't make my installation do what you've shown, and neither can I find where to change such settings. Can you show or link a screenshot of your C# (assuming that's what your code is) setting, as shown in the second image in my answer that I linked? Maybe we can "spot the difference"??

Comment: @AdrianMole: Thank you for trying to help. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a small bug in Visual Studio.
After I restarted Visual Studio, the behaviour is gone.
(Obviously I should have done that before asking questions...)

Comment: Most unusual ... a bug in Visual Studio! ;-)